# Ubuntu (percise): libopenblas-dev not available (Chromebook/Crouton)

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-chrome-os, openblas

Laptop: Asus C100P Chromebook

OS: CromeOS with Crouton (chroot) Ubuntu Percise Ver 12.04.5 LTS

Trying to set up my Python environment with Numpy and Theano.

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

output

```
Reading Package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libopenblas-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libopenblas-dev' has no installation candidate
```

there seem to be no resources to suggest that the BLAS package shouldn't be available. [[How to install libopenblas-dev percise]](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/precise/universe/libopenblas-dev/)

according to my limited knowledge [[this]](https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=arm&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=openblas) page would indicate that the ARM processor would have no problem with the package either, right?

is there another way to install this package?

EDIT: The packages i was trying to install (numpy and theano) seem to work without solving this problem. Could BLAS be base/native functionality in ChromeOS? (will keep question open in case libopenblas-dev may be an issue for future users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package is called libblas-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
```